# Is there a way to print lines from a file from n to m and than reverse their positions?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to print text from line 10 to 20 and then reverse their positions.

I've tried this:

```
sed '10!G;h;$!d' file.txt
```

But it only prints from 10 to end of the file. Is there any way to stop it at line 20 by using only one sed command?

Comment: I think it is possible duplicate of : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9356/how-can-i-print-lines-from-file-backwards-without-using-tac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost there, you just need to replace `$!d` with the 'until' line-number

```
sed -n '10,20p' tst.txt
// Prints line 10 <--> 20
```

```
sed -n '10!G;h;20p' tst.txt
// Prints REVERSE line 10 <--> 20
```

output:

```
20
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
```

tst.txt:

```
1
2
3
4
...
19
20
```

[Info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file)

Comment: Oh, that's what I wanted! Thank you very much :)

Comment: another way sed '10!G;h;20b;d'

Comment: Or since you are finished once you print the pattern space `sed '10!G;h;20!d;q' file`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to print a range of lines:

```
sed -n -e 10,20p file.txt | tac
```

`tac` will reverse the order of the lines

Comment: I know  there's a way by using tac. But I need to do that only by using one sed command. I had to mention that in the post, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

And for those of you without tac (like those mac users out there):

```
sed -n -e 10,20p file.txt | tail -r
```